# Duplicate Tag on Remote

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-tag

We are using Bitbucket as our remote for a git repository, and we somehow ended up with a duplicate tag (which I didn't think was possible).

When I try:

```
git push --delete origin refs/tags/mytagName
```

I get:

```
error: dst refspec refs/tags/mytagName matches more than one.
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://me@bitbucket.org/[etc]'
```

I can see both tags in the bitbucket UI, but (as far as I can tell) it does not have a feature that allows delete tags.

Any way of correcting this?

**Edit to answer some comment questions:**

> How do you observe duplicate tags? Using git log or some sort of a
>   GUI?

I can see the tags in the BitBucket UI.  I can also see the tags in my local git client (GitExtensions).

@torek: the duplicate tags do not have "^{}" in their name.

@torek and @Leon: the duplicate tag does appear twice in .git/packed-refs.  They show up as:

```
refs/tags/refs/tags/mytagName
refs/tags/mytagName
```

Comment: http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2013/06/13/git-having-a-branchtag-with-the-same-name-error-dst-refspec-matches-more-than-one/

Comment: @Leon I did see that post--it describes a situation where he had a branch and tag with the same name.  In my case they are both tags.  In any case, I tried what was suggested and got the same error.

Comment: There is no in-Git way to fix this, but there is also no in-Git way to break this in the first place (aside from bugs at least).

Comment: Can you clone the remote repo as a new local repo and check if the problem shows up in the local repo too?

Comment: @Leon yes, a fresh clone results in two local tags with the same name.

Comment: And where do those local tag objects live under `.git`? One should be `.git/refs/tags/mytagName`. What about the other one?

Comment: I can browse that folder, but I'm not sure what I should be looking for.  I see a refs/tags folder but it is empty.  I am not familiar (at all) with how git stores data.

Comment: How do you observe duplicate tags? Using `git log` or some sort of a GUI?

Comment: Besides @Leon's last question, it occurs to me that you may not be aware that annotated tags are normally shown *twice*: once as `refs/tags/tagX` (which gives you the hash ID of the tag object itself), and then again as `refs/tags/tagX^{}` (which gives you the hash ID of the *target* of the annotated tag object). The leading `refs/tags/` part may be stripped but the trailing `^{}` should not be, as it is critical to distinguishing the tag from its target.

Comment: Meanwhile, on a fresh clone, the tags will be found in `.git/packed-refs`, which is a newline-delimited plain-text file. Your local repository should have only one instance of the tag. None of this explains the failure of the bitbucket side to *delete* the tag, though.

Comment: So, in your fresh clone, does the duplicate tag appear twice in `.git/packed-refs`?

Comment: Guys, thanks for your help.  See my edits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comments above led me to the answer.

As noted in my edited question, the tag appeared twice in .git/packed-ref:

```
refs/tags/refs/tags/mytagName
refs/tags/mytagName
```

The following command deleted one of the tags:

```
git push --delete origin refs/tags/refs/tags/mytagName
```

I'm not clear on why "refs/tags" was duplicated, or how it got into the repo that way to begin with.